# Uncaught ReferenceError (variable is defined and show in console,but show me this error)

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code and the `ciso` variable is defined and its value is displayed when the code is executed, but when the `find_cites` function is executed, it shows the `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined` error.

```
function find_states(ciso){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://api.countrystatecity.in/v1/countries/' + ciso + '/states');

request.setRequestHeader('xx', 'xx');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    // console.log('Status:', this.status);
    // console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    // console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
    var items2 = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    var output2 = "<select name='state' class='form-select' aria-label='Default select example' style='width: 50%;margin-right: 5%;'>";
                // document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = items2;
                for(var key in items2){
                    console.log(items2[key]);
                    output2+='<option onclick="find_cites(' + ciso + ',' + items2[key].iso2 + ')">' + items2[key].name + '</option>';
                }
                output2+="</select>";
                document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = output2;
                // console.log(ciso);
  }
};

request.send();
};
function find_cites(ciso,siso){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

equest.open('GET', 'https://api.countrystatecity.in/v1/countries/' + ciso + '/states/' + siso + '/cities');

request.setRequestHeader('xx', 'xx');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    // console.log('Status:', this.status);
    // console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    // console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
    var items2 = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    var output2 = "<select name='city' class='form-select' aria-label='Default select example' style='width: 50%;margin-right: 5%;'>";
                // document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = items2;

                for(var key in items2){
                    console.log(items2[key]);
                    output2+="<option>" + items2[key].name + "</option>";
                }
                output2+="</select>";
                document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = output2;
                // console.log(ciso);
  }
};

request.send();
};
```

Comment: "x is not defined". Where is x in your code?

Comment: Having a typo is one thing, and ridiculous enough by itself, but intentionally tampering with the error to waste people's time is a new level of ignorant.

Comment: x is ciso variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got possible error here:

```
equest.open('GET', 'https://api.countrystatecity.in/v1/countries/' + ciso + '/states/' + siso + '/cities');
```

Should be:

```
request.open('GET', 'https://api.countrystatecity.in/v1/countries/' + ciso + '/states/' + siso + '/cities');
```

Comment: It's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

The ciso variable is a string and must be enclosed in quotation marks ('') when entering the function, but this was ignored when passing data to the function, and the error was related to this point.
The following codes are illustrative:

- Old code:

```
output2+='<option onclick="find_cites(' + ciso + ',' + items2[key].iso2 + ')">' + items2[key].name + '</option>';
```

- New code:

```
output2+='<option onclick="find_cites(' + "'" + ciso + "'" + ',' + "'" + items2[key].iso2 + "'" + ')">' + items2[key].name + '</option>';
```